# Java code int value not showing correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, integer

in my java code, I get the value of **a** as 814 and not 5814. why? what is wrong here? I'm using eclipse IDE.
The following code gives:
814
5
14
4
4

```
public class Hello {

    int a = 5814;
    
    int m = (a/1000);
    int p = (a %= 1000);
    int q = (p %= 100);
    int r = (q %= 10);

    public Hello() {    
        
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(q);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new Hello();

    }
}
```

Comment: You probably just want `%` instead of `%=` in all those initializations.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```java
int p = (a %= 1000);
```

the operator `%=` has a side effect on `a`: it assigns the value of the modulo operation to `a` (and also 'returns' it to get assigned to `p`); thus, overwriting its previous value. `5814 % 1000 = 814`, which is what is correctly printed.

Comment: ok. print statement just after   ```int a = 5814; ``` will show 5814 then. understood. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

because here(The variable a assigns itself the value mod 1000)

```
 int p = (a %= 1000);
```